How to make a POST request with headers using inetc::post in NSIS script
I need to make a POST API call when the user installs/uninstalls the program using NSIS script, but I don't know how to achieve this with headers consist of two keys AppId and AppKey. Here is my code for the script:
inetc::post "" "http://localhost:3000/api/uninstallations"

This link https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Inetc_plug-in instructs that I can add header like \HEADER "header: value" but I need to add two key-value pairs to the headers. Is there a way to work around this?

The header string is passed unchanged to WinINet, just add the CR/LF pair between each:
Section 
InitPluginsDir
inetc::get /header 'AppId: Acme App$\r$\nAppKey: 1234' "https://myhttpheader.com/" "$pluginsdir\tmp.htm" /END
Pop $1
DetailPrint $1
ExecShell "" "$pluginsdir\tmp.htm"
SectionEnd


I actually tried with one header as well but it doesn't seem to work.
inetc::get "" "http://localhost:3000/api/uninstallations" /SILENT /HEADER 'App-Id: valid_app_id'

I created two APIs with and without a header. The script works fine with the one without header but doesn't work in the other case.

The /header (and other switches except /END) must come before the URL.
